# Send and receive in different sockets in UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, boost-asio

Later in my application I will have three threads: one thread that listen data on a port, one thread that send the data to an address on the same port. The last one is not important here.

For the moment, I don't use threads, I just want to do some tests.

My problem is the following :

If I just use the server to send and receive data, there is no problem. But when it is the client that send the data, it's like the distant peer did not receive anything.

My code for server :

```
#include "server.h"


using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using Peer = udp::endpoint;

Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, Peer peer, Agent& agent) :  
    socket_(io_service, Peer(boost::asio::ip::udp::v6(), peer.port())),
    recv_buffer_(), send_buffer_(), root_(peer), agent_(agent)
{
/* //when this is uncomment, that works fine    
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Server Initialisation:";

    std::shared_ptr<PeersReq> peersreq(new PeersReq());
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tlv>> tlv_vector;
    tlv_vector.push_back(peersreq);
    Packet packet(tlv_vector);

    write_log(packet, peer);

    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream os(&request);
    packet.format(os);
    std::cout << peer.address() << std::endl;
    int n = static_cast<int>(socket_.send_to(request.data(),peer));

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "Bytes sent: " << n << std::endl;
*/
}

void Server::write_log(Packet packet, Peer peer) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info)  << "Packet send to " << peer.address().to_string() << ":" << peer.port() << std::endl;
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info)  << "Packet\n" << packet << std::endl;
}

void Server::receive() {
    Peer peer;
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Now listening on port:" << root_.port() << std::endl;
    socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), peer);
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Packet received" << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(recv_buffer_[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(recv_buffer_[1]) << std::endl;

    if (recv_buffer_[0] != 57) //TO DO magic number
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //Change this to send a bad
    else if(recv_buffer_[1] != 0) //TO DO magic number
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    uint16_t packet_length = static_cast<uint16_t>((recv_buffer_[2]<<8)+recv_buffer_[3]);
    std::cout << packet_length << std::endl;
    if (packet_length > 1024) //TODO magic number
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    //maybe log ?
    for(int i = 0 ; i < packet_length ; i++)
        std::cout << i << ":" << (static_cast<int>(recv_buffer_[i+4]) & 0xFF) << std::endl;

    Packet packet = Packet::from_string(recv_buffer_.data()+4, packet_length);
    std::cout << "packet received" << std::endl;
    std::cout << packet << std::endl;
    //agent_.notify(packet, peer);
    /*
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream os(&request);
    packet_to_send.format(os);
    //std::cout << request.size() << std::endl;
    socket_.send_to(request.data(), peer);
    */

    receive();
}
```

And the code for my client is the following :

```
Client::Client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, Peer peer) : socket_(io_service, Peer(boost::asio::ip::udp::v6(), peer.port())) , peers_(), queue_peer_() {
    //socket_.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v6());
    peers_.insert(peer);
    queue_peer_.insert(std::make_pair(peer.address().to_string(),std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tlv>>()));
    std::shared_ptr<PeersReq> peersReq(new PeersReq());
    add_tlv_to_queue(peersReq, peer);
    send();
}

void Client::add_tlv_to_queue(std::shared_ptr<Tlv> tlv, Peer peer) {

    if(queue_peer_.find(peer.address().to_string())!= queue_peer_.end()) {
        peers_.insert(peer);
        queue_peer_.insert(std::make_pair(peer.address().to_string(),std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tlv>>()));
    }

    queue_peer_.find(peer.address().to_string())->second.push_back(tlv);
}

void Client::send() {
    for ( std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tlv>>>::iterator it = queue_peer_.begin(); it != queue_peer_.end(); ++it ) {
        if(it->second.size()>0) {           
            boost::asio::streambuf request;
            std::ostream os(&request);
            Packet packet(it->second);
            packet.format(os);

            Peer peer = get_peer_from_string(it->first);
            std::cout << peer.address() << std::endl;
            int n = static_cast<int>(socket_.send_to(request.data(),peer));
        }
    }
}


Peer Client::get_peer_from_string(std::string string) {
    Peer peer;
    for(std::set<Peer>::const_iterator it =peers_.begin() ; it != peers_.end() ; it++) {        
        if(it->address().to_string() == string) 
            peer=*it;       
    }
    //undefined behaviour if the peer is not registred. But it shouldn't happen
    return peer;
}
```

In the main I use the following code :

```
Agent agent(storage, peer);
Server server(io_service_server, peer, agent);
Client client(io_service_client, peer);
server.receive();
```

I don't know if I did something bad or there is something special to get this behviour.

EDIT :

This is a snippet :

```
#include<array>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using Peer = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;


class Server {
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, Peer peer);
    void receive();

private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
    std::array<char, 1024> recv_buffer_;
};

Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, Peer peer) :
    socket_(io_service, Peer(boost::asio::ip::udp::v6(), peer.port())),
    recv_buffer_()
{
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream os(&request);
    os << "Server";

    int n = static_cast<int>(socket_.send_to(request.data(),peer));

}

void Server::receive() {
    Peer peer;
    socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), peer);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(recv_buffer_[0]) << std::endl;
    receive();
}

class Client {
public:
    Client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, Peer peer);
    void send(Peer peer);

private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
};


Client::Client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, Peer peer) : socket_(io_service) {
    socket_.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v6());
    send(peer);
}

void Client::send(Peer peer) {
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream os(&request);
    os << "Client";
    int n = static_cast<int>(socket_.send_to(request.data(),peer));        
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    boost::asio::io_service io_service_client;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_server;
    Peer peer;
    peer.address(); //Add an address here
    peer.port(12345);
    Client client(io_service_client, peer);
    Server server(io_service_server, peer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why? You don't need two sockets for UDP.

Comment: I need to send data even if I don't have received data from the server. How do you do that without two sockets ? Using asynchroneous ?

Comment: It would be helpful if this was made into a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will update my post. I don't know if it runs since I don't manage to compile this snippet.

Comment: @Saroupille What's the difference to your code whether it sends and receives on the same socket or different sockets? Whether you do things synchronously or asynchronously has nothing to do with which sockets you do it on, does it?

Comment: If the server is synchronously, therefore the call to receiv is blocking. However, while the server is blocking I wish to send some data. So, I cannot use the same socket to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.  The `main()` in the snippet differs greatly from the original question.  In particular, the snippet creates **temporary** `Client` and `Server` objects in a different order.  Is the actual code being debugged doing this as well?  It would explain the observed write/read behavior.  Furthermore, it explains how the `Server` and `Client` sockets are binding to the same address without an exception being thrown indicating that the address is already in use.

Comment: Sorry ! My bad. The object are not temporary. I just forgot to name them. The original code is with 2 distinct objects

Comment: If they are two distinct objects, then the snippet may not be properly reproducing the problem.  As can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a127d7acebbb2e43), attempting to bind to the same address results in an exception.  Based on the posted information, I would expect to observe the same exception in the original code.

Comment: Ok I had this problem also trying to fix the preivous one. In my program I don't bind the cient. Juste open the socket and send it.

Comment: Please take the time to update your question with actual code and a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It can be frustrating for all parties to debug an example that is neither complete, verifiable, nor reflective of the original code, and/or if the posted code doesn't reflect the actual code.  For instance, the non-snippet `Client` does bind the socket.  For what is worth, the snippet [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4bd96141feba9f6) after changing the order in which `Client` and `Server` are instantiated, and invoking `receive()` on the `Server`.

Comment: Yes I'm really sorry ! Should I open a new subject if I have a new problem or should I continue on this one ?